# PHP, Need number, don't get it

Tags: php

**Hi Stackers,**

I'm having a small problem with my PHP Code. It's a Crack the vault game, not finished. However, there is a problem. I Have the variable `$needednumber`, which I need to check if the user has another try or not, based on the selection which is saved in the variable `$vaultselection`.

When echoen the `$needednumber` Variable, I don't get any result, that's why I think that he isn't correctly checking. I've set myself to 0 Tries, however, it still passes the check.

What am I doing wrong?

**vault.php**

```
// Activate only when SET
    if(isset($_POST['crack_vault'])){

    // Get our cracker user id.
    $cracker = $user['id'];
    $cracktries = $user['try_vault'];

    // Get the Vault selection
    $vaultselection = $_GET['vaultoptions'];
    echo $vaultselection;

    // Check how many tries the cracker needs
    if($vaultselection = "mainvault"){
        $needednumber = "1";
    }else if($vaultselection == "bonusvault"){
        $needednumber = "2";
    }

    // Check if the cracker may try a crack, or else Continue
    if($cracktries < $needednumber){
        $error = "<div class='geenTeamlid' style='margin-bottom: 5px;'>Sorry, het is je <strong>niet</strong> gelukt iets uit de kluis te kraken!</div>";

    }else{

    // Get our beloved cracker his/her data.
    $vault_type = htmlentities($_POST['vault_picker']);
    $vaultnumber_one = htmlentities($_POST['vault_1']);
    $vaultnumber_two = htmlentities($_POST['vault_2']);
    $vaultnumber_three = htmlentities($_POST['vault_3']);
    $vaultnumber_four = htmlentities($_POST['vault_4']);

    // Get one string of four values. The final Vaultnumber.
    $vaultnumbers = array($vaultnumber_one, $vaultnumber_two, $vaultnumber_three, $vaultnumber_fout);
    $vaultnumber = implode("|", $vaultnumbers);

    // Let us check this shit. Can we find a match?
    if($vaultselection = "mainvault"){
            $check_codes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magical_gamevault WHERE (crackvalue = '".$vaultnumber."' AND vault = 'normal')");
    }else if($vaultselection = "bonusvault"){
            $check_codes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magical_gamevault WHERE (crackvalue = '".$vaultnumber."')");
    }

    // Get a final number as result. YES!
    $prizecount = mysql_num_rows($check_codes);

    // Show the user the result!
    if($prizecount < 1){
    $error = "<div class='geenTeamlid' style='margin-bottom: 5px;'>Jij hebt ".$cracktries." || Jij hebt nodig " .$needednumber. " || Jij koos " .$vaultselection. ".</div>";

    }else if($prizecount < 2){

    }   

    // End the if enough cracks check.
    }

    // End the set when someone posted a thing!
    }
```

Comment: Missing `=` in `$vaultselection = "mainvault"`? Edit: Multiple missing `=` in all your `if` statements?

Comment: The `$_GET` was indeed incorrect. I've added `=` too, however, this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, wow. Enjoy your SQL and HTML injection.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for pointing out, but a sentence like that will not help fix things. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Marvin,

```
if($vaultselection == "mainvault"){
    $needednumber = "1";
} elseif($vaultselection == "bonusvault"){
    $needednumber = "2";
} else { 
  # missing? security issue as $_GET data is easily manipulated
  # Setting this to 3 for could example would cause an SQL error
  $vaultselection = "mainvault";
  $needednumber = "1";
}
```

And..

```
if($vaultselection == "mainvault"){
    $check_codes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magical_gamevault WHERE (crackvalue = '".$vaultnumber."' AND vault = 'normal')");
} elseif($vaultselection == "bonusvault") {
    $check_codes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM magical_gamevault WHERE (crackvalue = '".$vaultnumber."')");
} else {
    die('unknown vault selection');
}
```

Without the `==` you are setting the variable and that will always be true so only the first statement will be used.

Also what I pointed out in the else comments, always expect that the data a user sends you will be invalid. Using the else statement you can prevent further script execution or correct the data forcing default settings.

Comment: Thanks, after a good look, I discovered a `=` to be missing. I will correct my IF statements, including your tips about the security. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to determine if vaultoptions is being set and if not - assign it a value that can be used.Also you are using $_GET for some of of hte code and $_POST for other part - is this correct? or should it be one or the other throughout?

```
if(isset($_GET['vaultoptions'])){
    $vaultselection = $_GET['vaultoptions'];}
else{ $vaultselection = "Not Selected";}
echo $vaultselection;
```

and then in your comparisons - you need to use the compare "==" rather than the assign "=" operator.

```
if($vaultselection == "mainvault"){
    $needednumber = "1";
}else if($vaultselection == "bonusvault"){
    $needednumber = "2";
}
```